# Why is `onEditingChanged` and `onCommit` not required SwiftUI TextField arguments based on the available `init` methods?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to understand how the below initialization of the `TextField` struct works in Swift UI.

```swift
TextField("Name", text: $name)
```

When using Xcode's "Jump to definition" feature, I see the below extension on `TextField` defining what seems to be all of `TextField`s `init` methods. In all of the `init` methods, `onEditingChanged` and `onCommit` seem to be required arguments. So, how is the above usage working?

```swift
extension TextField where Label == Text {
  public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, text: Binding<String>, onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }, onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = {})
  public init<S>(_ title: S, text: Binding<String>, onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }, onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = {}) where S : StringProtocol
  public init<T>(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, value: Binding<T>, formatter: Formatter, onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }, onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = {})
  public init<S, T>(_ title: S, value: Binding<T>, formatter: Formatter, onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }, onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = {}) where S : StringProtocol
}
```

Comment: "`onEditingChanged` and `onCommit` seem to be required arguments" - Umm... All of them seem to be optional to me... Note that they all have a default value of an empty closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the documentation in Xcode you will be able to see that onEditingChanged and onCommit have got empty closures provided as default:

```
init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey,
     text: Binding<String>,
     onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in },
     onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = {})
```